# Matching results count when there's not a 1:1 ratio of results

Tags: php, arrays

What I'm doing is scraping the contents of a web page by extracting the value from a div using xpath selectors. The amount of parent divs`$listing` is always the same. This div contains (most times) both a `$titlehit` containing a title like 'Guitar' and a `$pricehit` which contains prices like '199'. The problem is that there is not a 1:1 ratio of these divs. There can be 31 results on `$titlehit` and 29 on `$pricehit`. This causes the scraped data to be incorrect once it encounters a case where there's a title but no price. I'd like to know if there's some way to lock the count so both the title and price will be added to the same key in the array `$list` correctly.

Below is my code:

```
$listing = $xpath->query("//div[@class='cell-group listing']");
$titlehit = $xpath->query("//span[@class='mp-listing-title']");
$pricehit = $xpath->query("//span[@class='price-new']");

 $i = 0;

  foreach ($listing as $listings[$i]) {

    $titles = $titlehit[$i];
    $prices = $pricehit[$i];

      $list[]=['title'=>$titlehit[$i]->nodeValue,
               'price'=>trim($pricehit[$i]->nodeValue)];
   $i++
  }
```

I've tried with various if statements to only add entries with both a title and a price to the array `$list`, without results like this:

```
if (!empty($titlehit[$i]->nodeValue) && (!empty($pricehit[$i]->nodeValue))
```

There problem appears to be related to the count.

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why you use $i variable, could you please explain.

Comment: Thought it would lock the count like I would, it didn't, left it like this because it makes no difference.